# NetworkManager doesn't find predefined system-connections files

Tags: networkmanager

I'm creating a custom OS for Rasberry Pi using pi-gen.

I decided to install NetworkManager to manage connection/reconnection to the default network interfaces (eth0 and wlan0).

I crafted 2 configuration files located at /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections as follow:

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/wifi:`

```
[connection]
id=wifi
uuid=319f2d8e-3ce7-4e47-b6eb-fabb0aa69f68
type=wifi

[wifi]
mode=infrastructure
ssid=Facco

[wifi-security]
auth-alg=open
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=facco2016

[ipv6]
method=disabled

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ethernet:`

```
[connection]
id=ethernet
uuid=60d17e82-1be7-3d0f-b924-e980be41fcba
type=ethernet

[ipv6]
method=disabled

[ipv4]
method=auto
```

The 2 files worked perfectly.

After that I added the 2 configuration files to the OS repo and I generated the OS image.

Now when I start the OS I see the network-manager fine but the 2 files that I copied and pasted inside /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections are not seen at all by nmtui/nmtui-edit.

Shouldn't nmtui look inside the system-connection folder and find the file I pasted there?

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NetworkManager clients (like nmtui) never look at these files directly. They usually don't run as root and wouldn't have the permissions to read/modify them. Instead, they use NetworkManager's D-Bus API.

You are welcome to create connection profiles in the editor or pre-deploy them. That is, configuring files directly instead of using the D-Bus API is very much supported and what you try to do is fine.

Keyfile files (the connection profiles in`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections`) must be owned by root and have permissions `0600`. Check the files owner and permissions with `ls -l` and fix it with `chown` and `chmod`.

Less likely is that NetworkManager cannot access the files. Eg. we SELinux labels.

In any case, looking at NetworkManager's logfile would tell you why it doesn't load them. Check syslog/journal.

For example in CentOS 7 you may want to see this log file:

```
tail -f /var/log/messages
```

To intercept messages like this one:

```
... keyfile: error loading connection from file /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/example.conf: File permissions (100644) are insecure
```

Comment: It is worth noting that NetworkManager will not follow symlinks to a different filesystem!

Answer (score 0):

Not directly your answer, but for the rest of us who searched the Internet for `network manager manually configured system-connections file`.

After defining your `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eno2.nmconnection` with correct mode `0600` and owner `root:root`, you need to restart NetworkManager to get the updated changes. And maybe activate it too:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.service
sudo nmcli up eno2
```